# How to draw multiple bitmaps on canvas?

Tags: android, canvas, bitmap

I want to develop a game that shoots bullets on every touch of the canvas. 
It works but when I touch the canvas after shooting, he takes the bullet and restarts the shooting.
I just want the bitmap to create new bullet at every touch. Here is my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnTouchListener {

    DrawBall d;
    int x ;
    int y;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         d = new DrawBall(this);
        d.setOnTouchListener(this);
        setContentView(d);
    }

    public class DrawBall extends View {

        Bitmap alien;

        public DrawBall(Context context) {
            super(context);
            alien = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_launcher);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
            super.onDraw(canvas);

            startDraw(canvas);
        }

        public void startDraw(Canvas canvas){
            Rect ourRect = new Rect();
            ourRect.set(0,0, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight());

            Paint blue = new Paint();
            blue.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            blue.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);

            canvas.drawRect(ourRect, blue);

            if(y < canvas.getHeight()){
                y-=5;
            }

            canvas.drawBitmap(alien, x, y,new Paint());

            invalidate();
        }
    }

    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

        x = (int) event.getX();
        y = (int) event.getY();

        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I only superficially read the code. It seems that you are only keeping track of one bullet using the x y coordinates.The coordinates are resetting at every touch event, and thus you lose the previous bullet.

Use a dynamic array, or a linked list to keep track of all the bullets on the screen.
When there's a new touch, add the x,y to the array.
When drawing the bullet, iterate through your array to draw and update every bullet.
If the y-coordinate of any bullet goes out of the screen, delete the bullet from the array.

Comment: Thanks i know that is the problem , beacuse it's my first time to try develop games or someting like animation . where and when i need to add the ArrayList and remove the index ? if you can give me some exmple of code it will be great

Comment: I put together a little piece of code for you [here](http://pastebin.com/vqWJBdDN). It should help you work with arraylists in your project. Also read more on arraylists [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_arraylist_class.htm) and [here](http://voices.yahoo.com/java-tips-three-ways-iterate-through-arraylist-12321909.html)

Answer (score 0):

Each draw starts with a blank canvas.  So to draw multiple bitmaps you need to keep track of where to draw each bullet and call drawBitmap multiple times.

Also, calling invalidate in onDraw is a bad idea-  it will immediately invalidate, leading you to have performance issues.  I'd suggest invalidating on a timer instead.  Drawing too frequently will lead to performance issues.